# Change font size of mail list in Mail.app

Tags: messages, font

Is it possible to change the font size of list of mails on the left side inside Mail.app? I find it to be a bit too small for my liking.

Comment: Mail.app runs on macOS, iOS, iPadOS and the web via iCloud on many platforms. See the [tour] on how to edit enough details in for us to help without guessing or lots of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Go to Mail's preferences (Mail > Preferences... in the menu bar). Click on the Fonts & Colors tab. There you will find an option for "Message list font." Simply change the font size to your liking.

Comment: This option is gray

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: I need this as well but your answer has nothing to do with the sidebar, only the messages listed (hence "Message List Font")

Comment: Right, I’m assuming that’s what OP wanted